# javascript - change image width?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to check if the width of an image is larger than 700. If that the case then I want to set it to 700

```
    <img src="" id="main_image">
<script>
    if(document.getElementById(main_image).width > 700) {
    document.getElementById(main_image).width = 700;
    }
    </script>
```

after some search I found the above code but it is not working. Tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

use "main_image" instead of main_image

```
<script>
if(document.getElementById("main_image").width > 700) {
document.getElementById("main_image").width = 700;
}
</script>
<img src="" id="main_image">
```

or you can use style also

```
document.getElementById("main_image").style.width = "700px";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `style`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(+(document.getElementById('main_image').style.width) > 700) {
      document.getElementById('main_image').style.width = '700px';
    }
};
```

If you have set `width` attribute then you would use `getAttribute('width')` and `setAttribute(700)` or directly `width` as you were doing. But if it comes from CSS, you will need to use `style` like shown above.

Comment: This code worked, but the image is first loading in very large size then it is getting re-sized to width of 700. Any way I can fix this problem ?

Comment: @user1481850: Try specifying the initial width using css or `width` attribute like `<img width="your width here"`

Comment: what in case if I have an image with width that is less than 700 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably because you are running the script before the element exists on the page.  Try reversing the script and the img tag.